# Intuition for the chain homotopy of Poincaré lemma.

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology

In the proof of Poincaré lemma, Bredon essentially constructs a chain homotopy between the identity and the null map. Namely, for an open convex set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ containing the origin,  he builds
$$\phi: \Omega^{p+1} (U) \to \Omega^{p}(U) $$
as follows. For $\omega=fdx_{j_0} \wedge \cdots dx_{j_p}$, define
$$\phi(\omega)=\big(\int_0^1t^pf(tx)\big)\eta ,$$
where $\eta=\sum_{i=0} ^p (-1)^i x_{j_i}dx_{j_0} \wedge \cdots \wedge \widehat{dx_{j_i}} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{j_p}.$ Then extend linearly.

Now to check that it is a chain homotopy is just computation. What I don't get is how to come up with that idea.

Is there some intuition/motivation for considering this chain homotopy?

Comment: Aloizio: This is coming from integration over the fiber for the projection $\pi\colon U\times [0,1]\to U$. So it's "adjoint" to the usual map on simplicial or (smooth) singular homology that sends a $p$-chain $\sigma$ on $U$ to the $(p+1)$-chain $\sigma\times [0,1]$ on $U\times [0,1]$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for commenting! I think I have seen something similar to your explanation in Bott, Tu. Namely, there we consider $\pi: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and the inclusion $s: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}$. Then it seems to give rise to precisely what your comment is alluding. However, unfortunately I don't see the connection with this chain homotopy I referenced on the post. For example, it is not clear to me where the $t^p$ comes from, and it doesn't appear there in Bott, Tu. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Pull back $f dx_{j_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_{j_{p+1}}$ by the map $(x,t) \mapsto tx$. (This is where you use $U$ star-shaped with respect to the origin.) Note you'll pick up a factor of $t^p$ when you look at the $dt\wedge dx_J$ terms with $|J|=p$. By the way, your $\omega$ should be a $(p+1)$-form here. That'll help.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you very much! Since Bredon is going for de Rham theorem, your explanation of "adjointness" (together with everything else) was pretty helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on the comments: This is a special case of the [chain homotopy associated with a homotopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_along_fibers#Example) $M \times [0,1] \to N$.
With $\pi \colon M \times [0,1] \to M$ being the projection, we can let $\phi = \pi_* \circ h^*$
$$ \Omega^{p+1}(N) \xrightarrow{h^*} \Omega^{p+1}(M \times [0,1]) \xrightarrow{\pi_*} \Omega^p(M) $$
where $\pi_*$ is integration along the fiber. Then
$$ d\circ \phi + \phi \circ d = h_1^* - h_0^* \colon \Omega^p(N) \to \Omega^p(M)$$
so that $\phi$ is a chain homotopy between the chain maps $h_0^*$ and $h_1^*$.

In your case we have a homotopy $h \colon U \times [0,1] \to U, h(x,t) = tx$ from the constant map to the identity map (which only exists because $U$ is star-convex around $0$). Then we have $h^*(dx_j) = t \,dx_j + x_j \,dt$, so you can work out that, for $\omega=f \,dx_{j_0} \wedge \cdots dx_{j_p}$,
$$h^*(\omega)(x,t) = t^{p+1} f(tx) dx_{j_0} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{j_p} + t^p f(tx) \,dt \wedge \eta,$$
where $\eta$ is as you defined. Then integrate:
$$ \phi(\omega)(x) = \pi_*(h^*(\omega))(x) = \int_0^1 t^p f(tx) \,dt \cdot \eta.$$
Now $\phi$ is a chain homotopy between $h_0^* = 0$ and $h_1^* = \operatorname{id}$ and you're done.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer! Just to be sure, it should be $h^*(dx_j)=tdx_j+ x_jdt$, right?.

Comment: @Aloizio, Yes, it should :)